# Removing rows based on condition Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

Let's assume I have a dataset which contains the following data :

```
data = [('James','Smith','M',30),('Anna','Rose','F',41),
('Robert','Smith','M',62),('Jake','Rose','M',21) ]
```

I now want to remove all row that contains the same last name and gender (first and third row in the above dataset) using Pyspark.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

```
with_duplicates = data.groupBy("last_name", "gender").agg(count("*").alias("count")).where(col("count") > 1)

without_duplicates = data.join(with_duplicates, ["last_name", "gender"], "left_anti")
```

Comment: Thank you,  I tried with dropduplicates, it removes the row if there is a duplicate in any col.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Should be working.

Comment: @samkart no unfortunately not, since he want to remove both rows, that contain duplicates. .dropDuplicates() drops only one row if there are duplicates.